# Why does MediaPlayer silently fail if started before rendering has occurred?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I found this odd behavior with `MediaPlayer` by accident while helping someone with a problem and I want to see if any WPF guru's can explain it. I understand the below example is not practical, but it best demonstrates the behavior.

Lets say I throw a `MediaPlayer` in the MainWindow constructor and try to start it.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    mp.Open(new Uri("Be Free.mp3", UriKind.Relative));
    mp.Play();
}
```

The `MediaPlayer` will silently fail and you will hear no music play. Now here is where things get interesting. Let's say we throw an `OpenFileDialog` in there before we start playing.

```
public MainWindow()
{
        InitializeComponent();
        MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
        mp.Open(new Uri("Be Free.mp3", UriKind.Relative));

        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.ShowDialog();

        mp.Play();
}
```

The music will begin to play with no problem. You don't even have to select a file, you can just Cancel the Dialog and it will work.

For reference, I am `Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog`. Can anyone explain how activation of this allows the `MediaPlayer` to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expect this would have to do with the GC cleaning up your instance of `MediaPlayer` as it is defined within the constructor.

As a test I built a small example and subclassed the `MediaPlayer` as such and break point on the finalizer. Sure enough the finalizer was called shortly after my window appeared.

```
public class MyMediaPlayer : MediaPlayer
{

    ~MyMediaPlayer()
    {

    }
}
```

This was tested with a similar call in my window constructor.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MyMediaPlayer _mp;
    _mp = new MyMediaPlayer();
    _mp.Open(new Uri("song.m4a", UriKind.Relative));
    _mp.Play();
}
```

Now if when i made `_mp` an instance level object such as.

```
MyMediaPlayer _mp;
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _mp = new MyMediaPlayer();
    _mp.Open(new Uri("song.m4a", UriKind.Relative));
    _mp.Play();
}
```

I no longer experienced this issue and the finalizer was only hit when appropriate (ie closing the window).

**note the subclass is not required and only used for finalizer illustrations**

Comment: That's really interesting! Why on earth would a Dialog prevent Garbage Collection on the MediaPlayer though?

Comment: @Tronald to be honest the same thing still happens with the open file dialog my thoughts would be around when the Open File dialog is being finalized. On a test I moved the OFD above the media player initialization and it shut down shortly after.

Comment: Yep you're totally right. I let the music go longer and it eventually finalized (about 15 seconds in). Thanks for the explanation!